# Power automate custom connector that can be used with multiple endpoints

Tags: power-automate, power-automate-custom-connector

Is there a nice way for a power automate custom connector to support multiple server addresses?
The method I found on the web seems to be where each and every operation would require a URL query parameter which is used to update the host URL. Is this the only way?

Also need to mention I am using an on-premises API exposed by the on-premises gateway.

Comment: Pauto uses swagger 2.0, which only supports just a single host URL. You _could_ maybe wiggle that in the post-run code section, if also somehow azure authentication would be ok with running that connection call through to that url.